# How to move the data from one DynamoDB table to other DynamoDB table in the same region on click of HTML button

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am very new to AWS. As the first step I am creating an eCommerce application on my personal interest to give the demo of this application to my colleagues.

I am implementing 'Order' part. For this, I am thinking of moving the data from one table to other. I.e Once the user add the product to cart , it will saved in Cart table in dynamo-db  and in cart screen when the user clicks on 'Order'button/Link, the same data as it is in cart table should be moved to Order table and the cart should be empty So, the order can be confirmed.

How could I implement it? Not sure the method I am thinking is right if there any other method to accomplish Order functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is really going to depend on your architecture and stack - and even within that you have lots of options.

In a serverless way, i.e. from a static html page with no server-side backend, you could create a lambda function in the supported language of your choice and with the proper IAM role, to move the data from one table to the other - your html page could call it via an API call, and I would suggest you use AWS API Gateway to expose an api endpoint that then calls the lambda function.

If on (one of the other many) other-hands, say you were using ASP.net or PHP on the server side, you could use the AWSSDK to talk to the dynamodb directly and accomplish the same thing.

Besides these two options there are many, many alternatives and variations - and with all of the options you are also going to need to deal with authentication/security to make sure no one can make calls to your database/service that they aren't permitted to - perhaps not important for your demo application, but will definitely be an issue if/when you go live.

Comment: I am using serverless backened with static HTML and writing lambda functions in node.js. Can you please suggest me any hint to accompolish this.

Comment: Used Api Gateway to do this